# How to get around when an image doesn't exist for a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a problem to display the ImageNotFound when my database doesn't have an image set for an article  in my webstore.   I got the error Value cannot be null or empty.

The imageArticle is null when I debug it.  I don't know but is seems the ImageArticle from the DB is causing this error.  Any way I can't bypass it ?

I added an @if condition to check the null but it doesn't see to like it.

The database is containing a description, price and quantity but the image path has not been store.  It is set to null.  (this is because I want to allow the user to create new article in the webstore but maybe he doesn't have any picture yet for this new added item.

Here is the Browse.html

```
 @model IEnumerable<MyWebStore.Models.Product>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
  }

  <h2>Make your Selection</h2>


  <table>
     <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageArticle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>

        <th></th>
     </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
       <tr>
          <td>
              @if (item.ImageArticle == null)
                 {
                    <img class="img_set_size" src="~/Images/ImageNotFound.jpg" />
                 }          <====  the error occurs here
              Else
                 {
                    <img class="img_set_size" alt="Image" src="@Url.Content(item.ImageArticle)"  
                    />
                 }
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
          </td>

          <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "AddToCart", "Cart", new { id = 
                  item.ProductId }, null)

          </td>
       </tr>
      }

  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
@if (item.ImageArticle == null)
{
<img class="img_set_size" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/ImageNotFound.jpg")" />
}    
else
{
<img class="img_set_size" alt="Image" src="@Url.Content(item.ImageArticle)"/>
}
```

Comment: The only problem is I am seeing the else {   when it display the picture.  I think it is because it is display everything inside the @ after the If statement.  Any other way we can only display the image inside the { }   and not everything ?

Comment: If you're seeing the Razor code showing up in the browser you most likely forgot to close a tag somewhere. The above code should work as is.